# Grunt-jsmart doesn't create any files and fails to report any error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, smarty

I've recently been experimenting with grunt and jsmart and happened upon the [grunt-jsmart](https://github.com/hereandnow/grunt-jsmart) plugin. It's exactly what I was looking for but for some reasons I can't get it to work in my grunt workflow. It simply doesn't spit out a file (dest/books.html in this case)

I've tried several of the examples without luck but grunt doesn't spit out any errors. It simply says

```
Running "jsmart:files" (jsmart) task
Done, without errors.
```

My Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    jsmart: {
        options: {
            templatePath: 'src/templates',
            data: 'src/data/books.json'
        },
        files: {
            'dest/books.html': ['src/templates/books.tpl'],
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsmart');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jsmart']);

};
```

My src/templates/books.tpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{$books.greeting}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

src/data/books.json

```
{
   "greeting": "Hi there are some JScript books you may find interesting"
}
```

Has anyone gotten grunt-jsmart to work or am I doing something wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the task-target is missing (and as i recognize wrong in the documentation, sorry about that!)

that should work:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    jsmart: {
        options: {
            templatePath: 'src/templates',
            data: 'src/data/books.json'
        },
        someTargetName: {
            files: {
               'dest/books.html': ['src/templates/books.tpl']
            }
        }
    }
});
```

i'll fix the docs as soon as possible (would be great if you file an issue!)